# How to make Clack write the access log to a file?

Tags: http, web, common-lisp

The access-log can be enabled via 'lack:middleware:accesslog' package.
But I'm unable to figure out if this can also log to a file and if, how.

Anyone done that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to keep you waiting.

Here's a simple example of logging to a file.  Note that if the file is brand new and an error happens, the file may be removed.

Once the forms below are loaded, browsing http://localhost:5000 adds log lines to `/tmp/accesslog.txt`.

```
(ql:quickload '(:clack :lack-middleware-accesslog))

(defun router (env)
  (declare (ignorable env))
  (let ((status-code 200)
        (default-mime-type "text/plain")
        (greeting "Hello world"))
    (list status-code 
      (list :content-type default-mime-type)
      (list greeting))))

(defparameter *app* 'router)

(defvar *log-stream* (open "/tmp/accesslog.txt"
                           :direction :output
                           :if-does-not-exist :create
                           :if-exists :append))

(defun file-logger (logtext)
  (write-line logtext *log-stream*)
  (finish-output *log-stream*))

(defparameter *app-with-logging*
   (funcall lack.middleware.accesslog:*lack-middleware-accesslog* 
            *app* 
            :logger 'file-logger))

(defparameter *handler* (clack:clackup *app-with-logging* :port 5000))

;; (progn (clack.handler:stop *handler*) (close *log-stream*))
```